# Strange differences between decoding UTF8 with forge in javascript and Java

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, utf-8, decode

I'm trying to use forge.util.decodeUtf8 in javascript but I have not the same result with java, can you help me ?

```
var a = forge.util.hexToBytes("037A4078C3AD65C38863226AC3BD64C2B5392C6CCB8646617075342B473079C3954FC2A553C3BE6D");
aDecoded = forge.util.decodeUtf8(a);
console.log(forge.util.bytesToHex(aDecoded);
>> 037a4078ed65c863226afd64b5392c6c2c646617075342b473079d54fa553fe6d
```

This is the result in java

```
byte[] a = hexToBytes("037A4078C3AD65C38863226AC3BD64C2B5392C6CCB8646617075342B473079C3954FC2A553C3BE6D");

String aDecoded = new String(a, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
byte[] r = test.getBytes();

System.out.println(bytesToHex(r));
>> 037A4078ED65E863226AFD64B5392C6C8866617075342B673079F56FA573FE6D
```

The difference in the result it's here

```
037a4078ed65c863226afd64b5392c6c**2c64**6617075342b473079d54fa553fe6d
037A4078ED65E863226AFD64B5392C6C**8866**6617075342B673079F56FA573FE6D
```

I don't understand why I have different result.

Comment: In the Java statement `byte[] r = test.getBytes();` you are using the variable `test` which has not been declared in your Java code sample.

Comment: You should not use `test.getBytes()`, always explicitly specify the character set, eg `test.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`, otherwise it might use a different character set than you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted byte sequence can be decoded into a UTF8 string, as can be easily verified using a [UTF8 table](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm). Note, however, that generally an *arbitrary* byte sequence cannot be converted into a UTF8 string, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098022/problems-converting-byte-array-to-string-and-back-to-byte-array).

The Forge code contains a bug that causes the wrong result: The hexadecimal string is converted into a binary encoded string of bytes with [`hexToBytes`](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/lib/util.js) and decoded into a UTF8 string with [`decodeUtf8`](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/lib/util.js). For the reverse, the UTF8 string must first be encoded into a binary encoded string of bytes with [`encodeUtf8`](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/lib/util.js) and converted into a hexadecimal string with [`bytesToHex`](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/lib/util.js). In the posted Forge code the encoding with `encodeUtf8` is missing. With

```
console.log(forge.util.bytesToHex(forge.util.encodeUtf8(aDecoded)));
```

the correct result is displayed.

There are two minor issues in the Java code: The variable `test` isn't defined and must be replaced by the variable `aDecoded`. Furthermore, when calling the method [`getBytes`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()), the UTF8 encoding should be specified, otherwise the default platform charset is used, which is a possible error source. Apart from that, the Java code seems to be correct. However, since the two methods `hexToBytes` and `bytesToHex` haven't been posted, it cannot be ruled out that the error may be here. If e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/140861) implementation is used for `hexToBytes` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9855338) implementation for `bytesToHex`, the correct result is displayed.