# AES encryption and decryption of files using crypto-js

Tags: javascript, aes, cryptojs

I currently have such a requirement, but I cannot decrypt the encrypted file, the generated file is always damaged and cannot be opened, and I do not know where the problem lies. The code posted below is the code I use in VUE.

```
Encode() {
           let CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
            this.file_mime = this.file.type;
            this.file_name = this.file.name;
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => {
                let key = "1234567887654321";
                // let wordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(reader.result);
                // let plaintext = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(wordArray);
                let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(reader.result, key).toString();

                this.file2 = new Blob([encrypted], {
                    type: this.file_mime
                });
                const a = document.createElement("a");
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.file2);
                const filename = this.file_name;
                a.href = url;
                a.download = filename;
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            };
            reader.readAsBinaryString(this.file);
        }

Decode() {
            let CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => {
                let key = "1234567887654321";
                let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(reader.result, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
                this.file2 = new Blob([decrypted], {type: this.file_mime});
                const a = document.createElement("a");
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.file2);
                const filename = this.file_name;
                a.href = url;
                a.download = filename;
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            };
            reader.readAsBinaryString(this.file);
        }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In JavaScript there are several types for arrays: [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) and [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays). CryptoJS also uses [`WordArray`](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input). You have to convert between these types properly.

For encryption, [`FileReader.readAsBinaryString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FileReader) should be replaced by [`FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FileReader), which returns the binary data from the file as an `ArrayBuffer`. In the encryption-method the `ArrayBuffer` can be converted into a `WordArray` which can be processed directly by `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt`. `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt` returns the ciphertext as `CipherParams` object ([here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-output)), which is converted with `toString()` into a Base64 encoded string in OpenSSL format. This string can be used to directly create the blob.

Note: Since the key is passed in `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt`as a string, it is interpreted as a passphrase and a random 8 bytes salt is generated applying the same algorithm that OpenSSL uses, from which, together with the passphrase, key and IV are generated. The ciphertext is preceded by a 16 bytes block consisting of the ASCII encoding of `Salted__`, followed by the 8 bytes salt, and the whole stuff is Base64 encoded. In this OpenSSL format the Base64 encoded data therefore starts with `U2FsdGVkX1`, [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input) and [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#interoperability).

Changes in the encryption-method:

```
function encrypt(input) {
    var file = input.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
        var key = "1234567887654321";
        var wordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(reader.result);           // Convert: ArrayBuffer -> WordArray
        var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(wordArray, key).toString();        // Encryption: I: WordArray -> O: -> Base64 encoded string (OpenSSL-format)

        var fileEnc = new Blob([encrypted]);                                    // Create blob from string

        var a = document.createElement("a");
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileEnc);
        var filename = file.name + ".enc";
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

Note: Since the encrypted data are Base64 encoded and the Base64 encoding has an [overhead of 33%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding), the encrypted data are correspondingly larger compared to the unencrypted data.

For decryption, `FileReader.readAsBinaryString` should be replaced by [`FileReader.readAsText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FileReader), because the encrypted data are stored as a Base64 encoded string (in OpenSSL format), which can be passed directly to `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt`. This string is implicitly converted into a `CipherParams` object ([here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input), alternatively, a `CipherParams` object can be explicitly passed). `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt` returns the decrypted data as `WordArray`, so that a conversion into a typed array or `ArrayBuffer` is necessary to create the blob. For this the following function can be used:

```
function convertWordArrayToUint8Array(wordArray) {
    var arrayOfWords = wordArray.hasOwnProperty("words") ? wordArray.words : [];
    var length = wordArray.hasOwnProperty("sigBytes") ? wordArray.sigBytes : arrayOfWords.length * 4;
    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(length), index=0, word, i;
    for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
        word = arrayOfWords[i];
        uInt8Array[index++] = word >> 24;
        uInt8Array[index++] = (word >> 16) & 0xff;
        uInt8Array[index++] = (word >> 8) & 0xff;
        uInt8Array[index++] = word & 0xff;
    }
    return uInt8Array;
}
```

Note: A conversion of the `WordArray` into an Utf8-string (as in the posted code) is not possible and generally corrupts the data, because binary data (e.g. from a pdf) contain arbitrary byte sequences that generally do not correspond to Utf8 encodings (because binary data do not contain printable characters), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9098905).

Changes in the decryption-method:

```
function decrypt(input) {
    var file = input.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
        var key = "1234567887654321";  

        var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(reader.result, key);               // Decryption: I: Base64 encoded string (OpenSSL-format) -> O: WordArray
        var typedArray = convertWordArrayToUint8Array(decrypted);               // Convert: WordArray -> typed array

        var fileDec = new Blob([typedArray]);                                   // Create blob from typed array

        var a = document.createElement("a");
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileDec);
        var filename = file.name.substr(0, file.name.length - 4) + ".dec";
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got the answer I wanted from it!

Comment: The encryption/decryption with integrated API WebCrypto doesn't work with large files (depending of client computer, but often ~1GB). We should chunk the file and then processing the encrypted chunks. Does CryptoJS manages that alone? Does it work with huge files?

Comment: S. [Progressive Ciphering](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#progressive-ciphering). If you have further questions, please ask a new question.