# NodeJs encrypt using pbkdf2Sync and decrypt in java

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, aes, aes-gcm

I encrypt some data in NodeJs using below method. It works fine on Nodejs server to encrypt and decrypt.

Input for encryption = "SIYdcYSyiWY5XUqYMrfv31sPF8DSojs1ikghMs4R"

Encrypted Output in NodeJS = "IRhqmwhlFUxS1Zg+Qyr2ykSkAA1cQ5gVts7RIZoULCbYMS/DVsdfTyanGAAu4HkuAZv4ynk+VBPZ6vaTH5xTONfuVRlUavF9X//12v5et5em1ItPYdlOWkYo5IkodpAQvm5Yrm4F5xaRxRU3+TAZzOQm/3YQIlz74X+3V3/aV/K4qFebSLUMZJM9glPWo4O+ISDf76ztiN2ynLyvsivSU/qUuQEtPVEK"

```
encryptAES = ((text) => {
    // random initialization vector
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);

    const salt = crypto.randomBytes(64);

    var masterKey = crypto.randomBytes(32);

    const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(masterKey, salt, 2145, 32, 'sha512');

    // AES 256 GCM Mode
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);

    const encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(text, 'utf8'), cipher.final()]);

    // extract the auth tag
    const tag = cipher.getAuthTag();

    // generate output
    return Buffer.concat([salt, iv, tag, masterKey, encrypted]).toString('base64');
});
```

I try to decrypt it on the Java client but for some reason its failing. I am pretty sure that I am not using the correct way to decrypt. Below is how far i got

```
    public String decrypt(String base64EncryptedData) throws Exception {

        byte[] decryptedData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64EncryptedData);

        byte[] salt =  Arrays.copyOfRange(decryptedData, 0, 64); 
        byte[] iv = Arrays.copyOfRange(decryptedData, 64, 80); 
        byte[] tag = Arrays.copyOfRange(decryptedData, 80, 96); 
        String masterKey = new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(decryptedData, 96, 128), "UTF-8"); 
        byte[] text = Arrays.copyOfRange(decryptedData, 128, decryptedData.length); ;
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(tag.length * 8, iv);

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(masterKey.toCharArray(), salt, 2145, 32*8);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        key = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, gcmParameterSpec);

        byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(text);
        return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
    }
```

In Java I get exception

```
javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
```

Comment: What is the error that clients give?  512 in PBEKeySpec is not correct. In multiple platform questions, it is better to provide the input and outputs.

Comment: @kelalaka i updated it with the encrypted string

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems in the code:

- The most serious is that the password is sent with the message. This allows anyone to decrypt the ciphertext. The password must be secret, must not be sent with the message, only the sender and recipient may know it.
- The key `tmp`, derived in the Java code with `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512`, is an instance of `PBKDF2KeyImpl`, which stores the password in a `char[]` whose characters will be UTF8 encoded (see the documentation of the [`PBKDF2KeyImpl`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/0368f3a073a9/src/java.base/share/classes/com/sun/crypto/provider/PBKDF2KeyImpl.java) class). In the NodeJS code, however, the password is generated by filling a buffer pseudo-randomly using [`crypto.randomBytes`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback). Random binary data cannot usually be converted into a string using UTF8 encoding without corrupting the data, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9098905). To avoid this problem, either UTF8 encodable data or BouncyCastle's [`PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/index.html), which expects a `byte[]` (in `PBEParametersGenerator#init`), must be used, depending also on the context in which the KDF is applied (e.g. deriving the key from a password or from a master key, [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62809)).
- In Java, the ciphertext and authentication tag are not processed separately, but as a single `byte[]`, with the tag appended to the end of the ciphertext. In the current Java code, the authentication tag is separated but not used anywhere (except as a reference for its length in the `GCMparameterSpec` constructor).
- Also note the recommendations regarding the PBKDF2 parameters, especially regarding the iteration count, [RFC8018](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8018#section-4), sections 4.1 and 4.2 and [here](https://cryptosense.com/blog/parameter-choice-for-pbkdf2/).