# Unable to verify RSA-PSS signature in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, digital-signature, public-key

I have a client in *JavaScript* and a server in *Node.JS*. I'm trying to sign a simple text in client and send the signature along with publicKey to the server then server can verify the publicKey.

Anything in client-side is OK! but I'm unable to verify the signature in server-side. I think there is no need for you to read the client code but just for assurance I'll provide it too.

Client code:

```js
let privateKey = 0;
let publicKey = 0;
let encoded = '';
let signatureAsBase64 = '';
let pemExported = ''
function ab2str(buf) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
}

function str2ab(str) {
  const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
  const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}
let keygen = crypto.subtle.generateKey({
  name: 'RSA-PSS',
  modulusLength: 4096,
  publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1,0,1]),
  hash: 'SHA-256'
  }, true, ['sign', 'verify']);

keygen.then((value)=>{
    publicKey = value.publicKey;
    privateKey = value.privateKey;
    let exported = crypto.subtle.exportKey('spki', publicKey);
    return  exported
}).then((value)=>{
    console.log('successful');
    const exportedAsString = ab2str(value);
    const exportedAsBase64 = btoa(exportedAsString);
    pemExported = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n${exportedAsBase64}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;
    //signing:
    encoded = new TextEncoder().encode('test');
    let signing = crypto.subtle.sign({
          name: "RSA-PSS",
          saltLength: 32
      },
      privateKey,
      encoded);
    return signing;
}).then((signature)=>{
    const signatureAsString = ab2str(signature);
    signatureAsBase64 = btoa(signatureAsString);
    //verifying just to be sure everything is OK:
    return crypto.subtle.verify({
          name: 'RSA-PSS',
          saltLength: 32
      },
      publicKey,
      signature,
      encoded)
}).then((result)=>{
    console.log(result);
    
    //send information to server:
    let toSend = new XMLHttpRequest();
    toSend.onreadystatechange = ()=>{
       console.log(this.status);
    };
    toSend.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:3000/authentication", true);
    let data = {
      signature: signatureAsBase64,
      publicKey: pemExported
    };
    toSend.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    toSend.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    
    //to let you see the values, I'll print them to console in result:
    console.log("signature is:\n", signatureAsBase64);
    console.log("publicKey is:\n", pemExported);
}).catch((error)=>{
  console.log("error",error.message);
})
```

Server Code(I use express for this purpose):

```
const express = require('express');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const router = express.Router(); 

function str2ab(str) {
  const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
  const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}

router.post('/authentication',  async (req, res)=>{
    try{
        const publicKey = crypto.createPublicKey({
            key: req.body.publicKey,
            format: 'pem',
            type: 'spki'
        });
        console.log(publicKey.asymmetricKeyType, publicKey.asymmetricKeySize, publicKey.type);
        let signature = Buffer.from(req.body.signature, 'base64').toString();
        signature = str2ab(signature);
        const result = crypto.verify('rsa-sha256', new TextEncoder().encode('test'),
                        publicKey, new Uint8Array(signature));
        console.log(result);
    }catch(error){
        console.log('Error when autheticating user: ', error.message);
    }
})
```

Server Console Log:

```
rsa undefined public
false
```

**NOTE:**

1. I think the public key is imported correctly in server because when I export the
   public key again in server, the `pem` formats of both sides(client & server) are completely
   equal. so **I think the problem is associated with 'verification' or 'converting signature' in server**.
2. I prefer to use the built-in [crypto](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto) module if it's possible, so other libraries such as [subtle-crypto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/subtle-crypto) are my second options and **I'm here to see if this can be done with crypto or not**.
3. I want to learn how to verify a signature that is signed by [JavaScript SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto), due to this, Please don't ask some questions such as:

> Why do you want to verify the public key in server?

> Why don't you use 'X' library in client?

4. Feel free to change Exported format(pem), Public key format('spki'), Algorithm format(RSA-PSS) and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The failed verification has two reasons:

- The PSS padding must be specified *explicitly*, since PKCS#1 v1.5 padding is the default, s. [here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_verify_algorithm_data_key_signature).
- The conversion of the signature corrupts the data: The line:

  ```
  let signature = Buffer.from(req.body.signature, 'base64').toString();
  ```

  performs a UTF8 decoding, s. [here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end), which irreversibly changes the data, s. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9098905/9014097). The signature consists of binary data that is generally *UTF8 incompatible*. A conversion to a string is only possible with suitable binary-to-text encodings (like Base64, hex etc.), s. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding).
  But apart from that a conversion is actually not necessary at all, because the signature can be passed directly as a buffer, s. [here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_verify_algorithm_data_key_signature).

The following NodeJS code performs a successful verification (for a signature and public key produced with the client code):

```
const publicKey = crypto.createPublicKey(
    {
        key: req.body.publicKey,
        format: 'pem',
        type: 'spki'
    });

const result = crypto.verify(
    'rsa-sha256', 
    new TextEncoder().encode('test'), 
    {
        key: publicKey, 
        padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING
    }, 
    Buffer.from(req.body.signature, 'base64'));

console.log(result); // true
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This solved my problem and I understood what was my mistake.