# How to get raw output from SHA1 using JS as PHP does?

Tags: javascript, php, cryptography, sha1, cryptojs

I'm trying to dynamically generate a security header at **Postman pre-request script**. To do so, I need to transform the following code snippet from PHP to JS.

```
$password = "SECRETPASSWORD";
$nonce = random_bytes(32);
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$created = date(DATE_ATOM);
$encodedNonce = base64_encode($nonce);
$passwordHash = base64_encode(sha1($nonce . $created . sha1($password, true), true));
```

(Note the `true` flag at [php's sha1() function](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sha1.php), forcing raw output).

I've coded this code snippet so far:

```
var uuid = require('uuid');
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
var moment = require('moment');

// Generate messageId
var messageId = uuid.v4();
pm.environment.set('messageId', messageId);


// Generate nonce
var nonce = uuid.v4();
var encodedNonce = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(
    CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(nonce)
);
pm.environment.set('nonce', encodedNonce);

// Generate created
var created = moment().utc().format();
pm.environment.set('created', created);

// Generate password hash
var password = 'SECRETPASSWORD';
var rawSha1Password = Buffer.from(CryptoJS.SHA1(password).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64), "base64").toString("utf8");
var passwordHash =  CryptoJS.SHA1(nonce + created + rawSha1Password).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
pm.environment.set('passwordHash', passwordHash);
```

My JS script is almost working, the only problem seems to be the sha1 generation. Taking the following example values:

> **password**: SECRETPASSWORD
> **nonce**: 55d61876-f882-42f0-b390-dc662a7e7279
> **created**: 2021-01-21T18:19:32Z

The output from PHP is:

> **encodedNonce**: NTVkNjE4NzYtZjg4Mi00MmYwLWIzOTAtZGM2NjJhN2U3Mjc5
> **passwordHash**: olI18mUowhmeCwjb1FJNHtTHYDA=

But, the output from JS is:

> **encodedNonce**: NTVkNjE4NzYtZjg4Mi00MmYwLWIzOTAtZGM2NjJhN2U3Mjc5
> **passwordHash**: tk/uYkL/3Uq0oIkYO0nlBGnV/0E=

As you can see, the encodedNonce is built correctly; however the passwordHash value is different. As I'm using Postman, I have a limited JS libraries available.
Taking this into account, how can I get the same result as the PHP one?

Comment: `rawSha1Password` seems base 64 encoded when you hash it. It needs to be raw binary  (this is why `true` is in the call) when you rehash it.  I.e. just the output of `CryptoJS.SHA1(password)` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. The `CryptoJS.SHA1(password)` returns an WordsArray object; that's why I'm encoding to Base64 before creating the Buffer. If I try to encode to Utf8 at this point, the library throws an Error: Malformed Utf8 string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the line

```js
var rawSha1Password = Buffer.from(CryptoJS.SHA1(password).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64), "base64").toString("utf8");
```

the password hash is read into a buffer and then UTF-8 decoded. The UTF-8 decoding generally corrupts the data, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9098905/9014097). A possible solution is to concatenate the `WordArray`s instead of the strings:

```js
function getPasswordHash(test){

    // Generate nonce
    var nonceWA = !test ? CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(32) : CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('55d61876-f882-42f0-b390-dc662a7e7279'); 
    console.log('nonce (Base64):  ' + nonceWA.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)); 

    // Generate created
    var created = !test ? moment().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss[Z]') : '2021-01-21T18:19:32Z'; 
    var createdWA = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(created);
    console.log('created:         ' + created); 

    // Hash password
    var pwd = 'SECRETPASSWORD';
    var pwdHashWA =  CryptoJS.SHA1(pwd);

    // Hash nonce + created + pwd
    var passwordHash =  CryptoJS.SHA1(nonceWA.concat(createdWA).concat(pwdHashWA)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

    console.log('passwordHash:    ' + passwordHash);
}

getPasswordHash(true);    // with testdata
getPasswordHash(false);   // without testdata
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

When the code is executed, the first call of `getPasswordHash()` uses the test data for nonce and date (`test=true`), the second call applies a random nonce and the current date (`test=false`) . The call with the test data returns the same result as the PHP code:

```
nonce (Base64):  NTVkNjE4NzYtZjg4Mi00MmYwLWIzOTAtZGM2NjJhN2U3Mjc5
created:         2021-01-21T18:19:32Z
passwordHash:    olI18mUowhmeCwjb1FJNHtTHYDA=
```

CryptoJS implements [`CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random()`](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/971c31f0c931f913d22a76ed488d9216ac04e306/src/core.js#L352) as CSPRNG, which is the counterpart of the PHP method [`random_bytes()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php). The use of the *uuid* library is therefore actually not necessary. I have chosen `CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random()` in my example because it is closest to the PHP code.