# HMAC SHA-512 hashing function equivalent in node.js

Tags: python, node.js, cryptography, hmac, hashlib

I currently have this snippet in Python -

```py
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac
def hash_hmac(self, key, data):
    res = hmac.new(base64.b64decode(key), data.encode(), hashlib.sha512).digest()
    return res
```

I am trying to replicate it in Node.js, but having difficulty getting the correct hash.

```js
const crypto = require('crypto')
const hashHmac = (key, message) => {
  return crypto.createHmac('sha512', Buffer.from(key, 'base64').toString('utf-8'))
        .update(message)
        .digest()
        .toString('base64') 
}
```

Test case:
Key: '7pgj8Dm6'
Message: 'Test\0Message'

With the python snippet, the hash is

```
69H45OZkKcmR9LOszbajUUPGkGT8IqasGPAWqW/1stGC2Mex2qhIB6aDbuoy7eGfMsaZiU8Y0lO3mQxlsWNPrw==
```

With the js snippet, the hash is

```
OhaJU9IibhhjIjz3R7FmodgOBUPjwhndXX8gn0r2rRzjQvCJl4T40rHXKw3o6Y2JQ5fVHTeStu8K1DRMWxMGBg==
```

Am I going wrong with the base64 encoding?

Comment: In the NodeJS code replace `Buffer.from(key, 'base64').toString('utf-8')` with `Buffer.from(key, 'base64')`. The UTF-8 decoding corrupts the data.

Comment: Awesome it worked!, can you answer it so I can accept it :)

Comment: Sure. I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the NodeJS code, the key is first Base64 decoded and then UTF-8 decoded. Since the key contains byte sequences that are not defined by UTF-8, it is thereby damaged.

Arbitrary binary data, such as ciphertexts, hashes, or keys (at least if randomly generated), must be stored in binary, or a [binary-to-text encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) like Base64 must be used (and not a character set encoding like UTF-8) if they are to be converted to a string, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9098905).

In the posted example, converting the buffer to a string is not necessary at all. The key can simply be passed *directly* as a buffer, s. [`crypto.createHmac()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhmac_algorithm_key_options), i.e. as follows:

```js
var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', Buffer.from(key, 'base64'));
```

With this, the NodeJS code returns the same result as the Python code.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed NodeJs:

```sh
 echo "console.log(require('crypto').createHmac('sha512', 'nonbase64key').update('password').digest('hex'))" | node
```

it's equivalent in python is:

```sh
python3 -c 'import hashlib;import base64;import hmac;print(hmac.new(b"nonbase64key", "password".encode(), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest())'
```

And the equivalent pure shell command is:

```sh
echo -n "password" | openssl sha512 -hmac "nonbase64key"
```