# AES/GCM PBKDF2 Encryption for Kotlin and Dart

Tags: kotlin, dart, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am attempting to use GCM encryption with PBKDF2 that is interoperable across both kotlin and dart. Decrypters will come next. Currently I am using a "working" kotlin version (below) and I want to replicate it in dart (my attempt below that) if it is correct. See below Kotlin version (Notice log results provided below respective lines. Outputs are suspect.):

Also note: These examples now use the same text and masterpass inputs.

**KOTLIN:**

```
fun encrypt(input: String, password: String): String {
val masterpw = getKey(password).toString(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))

val mastertest = getKey(password)

val random = SecureRandom()
Log.d("RANDOM", "${random}") //D/RANDOM  (25834): java.security.SecureRandom@dc72083

val salt = ByteArray(8)
Log.d("SALT", "${salt}") //D/SALT    (25834): [B@202f200

random.nextBytes(salt)
Log.d("SALT2", "${salt}") //D/SALT2   (25834): [B@202f200

val factory: SecretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1")
Log.d("factory", "${factory}") //D/factory (25834): javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory@cfd3a39

val spec: KeySpec = PBEKeySpec(masterpw.toString().toCharArray(), salt, 10000, 256)
Log.d("KeySpec", "${spec}") //D/KeySpec (25834): javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec@a5587e

val tmp: SecretKey = factory.generateSecret(spec)
Log.d("SecretKey", "${tmp}") //D/SecretKey(25834): com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BCPBEKey@6d141df

val iv = ByteArray(12)
Log.d("IV", "${iv}") //D/IV      (25834): [B@aa52e2c

random.nextBytes(iv)
Log.d("IV2", "${iv}") //D/IV2     (25834): [B@aa52e2c

val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
Log.d("Cipher", "${cipher}") //D/Cipher  (25834): javax.crypto.Cipher@e6e40f5

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, tmp, IvParameterSpec(iv))
Log.d("Cipher2", "${cipher}") //D/Cipher2 (25834): javax.crypto.Cipher@e6e40f5

val cipherText: ByteArray = cipher.doFinal(input.toByteArray(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
Log.d("cipherText", "${cipherText}") //D/cipherText(25834): [B@f3a7e8a

val ivstring: String = Base64.encodeToString(iv, Base64.NO_WRAP)
Log.d("ivstring", "${ivstring}") //D/ivstring(25834): D3tPtM6+WYnoSswE

val saltystring: String = Base64.encodeToString(salt, Base64.NO_WRAP)
Log.d("saltystring", "${saltystring}") //D/saltystring(25834): zbq9ZqJ9xiw=

val cipherstring: String = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP)
Log.d("cipherstring", "${cipherstring}") //D/cipherstring(25834): w/WqSqg++udXCLKE6ly765OWBHKt79Lw/g==

val returnstring: String = ivstring + "-" + saltystring + "-" + cipherstring
Log.d("returnstring", "${returnstring}") //D/returnstring(25834): D3tPtM6+WYnoSswE-zbq9ZqJ9xiw=-w/WqSqg++udXCLKE6ly765OWBHKt79Lw/g==

return returnstring
}

fun getKey(masterPass: String): ByteArray {
    return masterPass.padEnd(32, '.').toByteArray(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
}
```

**DART:**

The dart method utilizes the cryptography.dart package v1.4.1. Note: Due to constraints with other libraries in the app, I can't use a newer version of the cryptography package, which I believe rules the recently added 'AesGcm.with128bits' functions out.
The dart version crashes near the end when I attempt to decode the encrypted cipherTextBytes to a string, as shown in the provided log results.

```
encryptPassGCM(String text, String masterPass) async {
print("ENCRYPTPASSGCM STARTS WITH: " + "TEXT: " + text + " & " + "master: " + masterPass);

//trim key and convert
String keyString = masterPass;
if (keyString.length < 32) {
  int count = 32 - keyString.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    keyString += ".";
  }
}

Uint8List keyStringutf8  = utf8.encode(keyString);
print("keyStringutf8: " + keyStringutf8.toString());

//gen salt and iv
final salt = Nonce.randomBytes(8);
print("salt init: " + salt.bytes.toString());
//LOG salt init: [161, 50, 222, 98, 151, 225, 89, 65]
final iv = Nonce.randomBytes(12);
print("iv init: " + iv.bytes.toString());
//LOG iv init: [59, 188, 146, 172, 213, 13, 135, 35, 202, 220, 178, 190]

//create key
final pbkdf2 = Pbkdf2(
 macAlgorithm: Hmac(sha1),
 iterations: 10000,
  bits: 256,
);
final keyBytes = await pbkdf2.deriveBits(
  keyStringutf8,
  nonce: salt,
);

print("keybytes: " + keyBytes.toString());
//LOG keybytes: [85, 204, 96, 108, 200, 21, 24, 115, 254, 104, 133, 81, 53, 126, 252, 161, 172, 193, 25, 177, 143, 69, 53, 35, 105, 144, 248, 6, 121, 106, 237, 142]
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKey(keyBytes);
print("secretKey: " + secretKey.toString());
//LOG secretKey: SecretKey(...)

//create ciphertext and convert to string
List<int> textutf8 = utf8.encode(text);
Uint8List cipherTextBytes = await AesGcm().encrypt(textutf8, secretKey: secretKey, nonce: iv); 
print("cipherTextBytes: " + cipherTextBytes.toString()); 
//LOG cipherTextBytes: [110, 3, 238, 169, 52, 125, 176, 200, 122, 142, 111, 75, 181, 248, 91, 57, 95, 131, 85, 223, 224, 73, 173, 39, 37]
var cipherText = utf8.decode(cipherTextBytes); //CRASHES HERE

print("cipherText: " + cipherText);
var cipherString = iv.toString() + "-" + salt.toString() + "-" + cipherText;
print("GCM CIPHER STRING COMPLETE: " + cipherString);
return cipherString;
}
```

1. Is the kotlin implementation correct? The data logs seem erroneous.
2. What is wrong with my dart implementation?

Comment: Just a note- your Kotlin logs print out the **object** and not the **content** of the variables. For a print out better use a hex- or Base64 encoding. What is wrong with your Dart version,  kindly provide the stacktrace.

Comment: Your Kotlin and Dart code do different things. Your Dart code, for example, creates keyBytes from the password and then throws it away. It then creates an random, unrelated secretKey that it encrypts with. I would walk through your code step by step and make sure that at each step the behavior is identical. Since you generate random values (which is normal), you should split your code up so that you can test pieces by passing in known rather than random values. The key to duplicating crypto code is making sure that every step along the way is byte-for-byte identical.

Comment: There is not part in your Kotlin code that generates 32 random bytes. The fact that your Dart code does generate 32 random bytes should be a screaming red flag.

Comment: @RobNapier WHOOPS! I actually just threw that random key generator in there during a test to see if my encrypter behaved differently. Forgot to remove it. It behaves the same with the generated key. Will edit the post to reflect.

Comment: In the Dart code, the components IV, salt and ciphertext must be Base64 encoded for compatibility with the Kotlin code. If this is fixed (and the key derived with PBKDF2 is used, s. Rob Napier's comment), both codes provide the same ciphertext on my machine (if IV and salt match).

Comment: Base64 encoded at which point? The AesGcm().encrypt function only accepts a "Nonce" as iv. pbkdf2.deriveBits function only accepts a "Nonce" as salt. Similarly, it requires List<int> as the ciphertext input.

Comment: @Topaco I think the Kotlin Base64-encoding is purely for printing at the end. The encryption is already done at that point. Did you mean something else?

Comment: You need something like `var cipherString = base64.encode(iv.bytes) + "-" + base64.encode(salt.bytes) + "-" + base64.encode(cipherTextBytes)` for compatability with the Kotlin code. Note that a UTF8 decoding generally corrupts arbitrary binary data such as the ciphertext (and also salt and IV).

Comment: @RobNapier: At some point the data must be concatenated for decryption, this seems to be the only place (although of course concatenation at byte level with subsequent Base64 encoding would be more efficient). Of course, if the line is only for output, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok I understand now that @topaco is referring to the concat values. I base64 encoded the cipherTextBytes and got cipherText: H4Hk9clMtIiDutWViFh1cwEQF4LRQWYfKw==. Will do the same for salt and iv and attempt to run through the kotlin decrypter.

Comment: Yep, the exception is caused by the UTF8 decoding of the ciphertext (line with comment _CRASHES HERE_) and this issue should be fixed by the Base64 encoding of the ciphertext.

Comment: @Topaco Thanks. I see where you're going with that.

Comment: Ok, that works! Does the implementation itself look OK?

Comment: Imo, yes, with 2 minor notes: Your concatenation differs from the convention: Usually salt, IV and ciphertext are concatenated without separator on byte level and the result is Base64 encoded. Since the lengths of salt and IV are known on both sides, a separation (after Base64 decoding) is feasible. And: The iteration count must be as high as possible with acceptable performance. The salt should be 16 bytes. See also e.g. [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2#Purpose_and_operation).

Comment: Great, thank you both. I confirmed your advice on the salt with official NIST recommendations. @Topaco If you provide a short answer below that summarizes your answers I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks again

Comment: Sure. I put my comments together in one answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is thrown when trying to Utf8 decode the ciphertext. Arbitrary binary data like ciphertexts or pseudo-random data like salts or IVs cannot be decoded with charset encodings like Utf8 because the data will be corrupted, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9098905). Instead, a binary-to-text encoding like Base64 must be applied.

The Kotlin code Base64 encodes salt, IV and ciphertext and concatenates the portions with a separator (-). The Dart counterpart would be e.g.:

```dart
var cipherString = base64.encode(iv.bytes) + "-" + base64.encode(salt.bytes) + "-" + base64.encode(cipherTextBytes);
```

and the UTF8 decoding of `cipherTextBytes` is to be removed.

A second problem was that by accident the originally posted code did not use the key derived using PBKDF2, but a randomly generated key (see also Rob Napier's comment).

When both bugs are fixed, both codes are functionally identical and produce the same ciphertext (assuming the same salt and IV).

---

Note that the GCM authentication tag (16 bytes by default) is automatically appended to the ciphertext in the Dart and Kotlin code (i.e. `cipherTextBytes` contains not only the ciphertext but also the authentication tag: `ciphertext|tag`). Not all libraries do it this way, so the separation of the tag (as the last 16 bytes) is required when decrypting with such a library.

Also, it is rather uncommon to Base64 encode salt, IV and ciphertext/tag separately and concatenate the parts with a separator. Instead, by convention, concatenation is done at byte level: `salt|IV|ciphertext|tag`. Since the salt, IV and tag lengths are known on both sides, no separator is needed. The result is Base64 encoded. But as mentioned, this is just a convention.

Regarding the parameters for PBKDF2: Although SHA1 is classified as insecure (see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/48291)), its use as [HMAC/SHA1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26510) is not critical. However, a move to SHA256 would support the banishment of SHA1 from the ecosystem. The iteration count should slow down an attacker and should therefore be chosen as high as possible while maintaining acceptable performance (typically larger than 10,000). The recommended salt length is 16 bytes, see [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2#Purpose_and_operation).