# SHA1 signature created in Java not being verified in PHP

Tags: java, php, encryption, cryptography

I am creating an RSA signature in Java and sending it in the Auth header to a PHP server which is then verifying it. The problem is that although the signature is being verified in Java, it is failing in PHP. How do I fix this?

```
private String getSignature(JsonObject body) {
    try {
        InputStream is  = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("private.key");
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        try (InputStreamReader keyReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
          PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(keyReader)) {

            PemObject pemObject = pemReader.readPemObject();
            byte[] content = pemObject.getContent();
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(content);
            PrivateKey privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(privKeySpec);
            System.out.println(privKey.getAlgorithm());
            Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
            sign.initSign(privKey);
            sign.update(body.toString().getBytes());
            verifySignature(body, sign.sign());
            return new String(sign.sign());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private String verifySignature(JsonObject body, byte[] bs) {
    try {
        InputStream is  = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("public.pem");
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        try (InputStreamReader keyReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
          PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(keyReader)) {

            PemObject pemObject = pemReader.readPemObject();
            byte[] content = pemObject.getContent();
            KeySpec privKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(content);
            PublicKey privKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(privKeySpec);
            System.out.println(privKey.getAlgorithm());
            Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
            sign.initVerify(privKey);
            sign.update(body.toString().getBytes());
            boolean res = sign.verify(bs);
            System.out.println(res);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

My PHP code where I'm verifying the sign:

```
$fp = fopen("public.pem", "r");
$pub_key = fread($fp, 8192);
fclose($fp);
$pubkeyid = openssl_pkey_get_public($pub_key);
$dd = ["email"=>"kkamran@gmail.com","password"=>"!Pass1234","platform"=>"con"];
$ss = base64_decode("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");
$ok = openssl_verify( $data, $ss, $pubkeyid, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);
```

---

Update:

I am now signing like this:

```
Signature sign = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
sign.initSign(privKey);
sign.update(body.toString().getBytes());
String signStr = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sign.sign());
verifySignature(body, signStr.getBytes());
return signStr;
```

Comment: The Base64 decoded signature in the PHP code contains many 0xEFBFBD sequences, which corresponds to the replacement character. This typically happens when binary data is UTF-8 decoded, which corrupts the data. In your code, this occurs in the line `return new String(sign.sign())`. Instead, the data should be Base64 encoded `return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sign.sign())`.

Comment: Also, before the second `sign.sign()` call, the `sign.update()` call must be performed again, otherwise an empty message will be signed (of course, it is more efficient to perform the `sign.sign()` call only once).

Comment: @Topaco I did what you said and I updated my question. But now when verifying, I am getting a `SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 344 but was expecting 256` error on the `boolean res = sign.verify(bs);` line.

Comment: Try the following: `byte[] signature = sign.sign(); verifySignature(body, signature); return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature);`

Comment: Yes, this got verified

Comment: @Topaco You can put this in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: My pleasure. I have put my comments in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```java
return new String(sign.sign());
```

in the `getSignature()` method performs an decoding of the signature with the default charset. From the posted signature it can be concluded that this is the UTF-8 charset. This UTF-8 decoding corrupts the signature!
Binary data like signatures, ciphertexts, hash values, random binary data etc. generally do not contain UTF-8 compliant byte sequences. When decoding with UTF-8, these non-compliant sequences are replaced by the [0xEFBFBD](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) replacement character, which *irreversibly* corrupts the data. The 0xEFBFBD byte sequence occurs with high frequency in the posted signature (after Base64 decoding), which is a clear indication of corruption resulting from UTF-8 decoding.
In general, charset encodings such as UTF-8 are not suitable for converting binary data to a string (unless, of course, the binary data was generated using that encoding). Instead, a [binary-to-text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding) encoding should be used, e.g. Base64, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9098905).

A second problem is the *double* `sign.sign()` call in `getSignature()`. A `sign()` call resets the state of the signature object to the state immediately after the last `initSign()`, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/security/Signature.html#sign()). I.e. in the present case the second call is made without the data from the `update()` call, so the signature is ultimately created for an *empty* message. This signature is returned and therefore of course does not correspond to the *actual* message, so that a later verification will fail.
A possible solution would be to additionally execute the corresponding `update()` call before the second `sign()` call.
Of course, in this particular case it is more efficient to execute the `sign.sign()` call only *once* and store the result to be able to use it later (as often as needed).

Both problems are successfully fixed as follows:

```java
...
byte[] signature = sign.sign(); 
verifySignature(body, signature); 
return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signature); 
...
```